# How to use a SQL query to get the Progress OpenEdge database information, e.g. database version

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

How to use a SQL query to get the Progress OpenEdge database information, e.g. database version?

In MS SQL Server, we can use `SELECT @@VERSION` to get the database version information, but this doesn't work for Progress OpenEdge database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get the version somewhat indirectly by looking at  _dbStatus._dbStatus-shmVers and then mapping that value onto the values listed in this kbase:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P39456

(A leading "64" means 64 bit.)

For instance, a shared memory version of 6412371 means that you have 64 bit 10.2b00, 13723 is 11.7.0 etc.

Obviously new releases will result in new shared memory versions so you may need to stay on top of the kbase.

But as of today the list is:

```
OpenEdge 11 Shared Memory Versions:

11.0.0 - 13019

11.1.0 - 13053

11.2.0 - 13102
11.2.1 - 13103

11.3.0 - 13205
11.3.1 - 13215
11.3.2 - 13217
11.3.3 - 13221

11.4.0 - 13312

11.5.0 - 13506
11.5.1 - 13507

11.6.0 - 13614
11.6.1 - 13614
11.6.2 - 13615
11.6.3 - 13615

11.7.0 - 13723
11.7.1 - 13723

OpenEdge 10 Shared Memory Versions:

10.0A00 - 10004

10.0B00 - 10036
10.0B01 - 10036
10.0B02 - 10036
10.0B03 - 10040
10.0B04 - 10042

10.1A00 - 10127
10.1A01 - 10129

10.1B00 - 10171
10.1B02 - 10173
10.1B03 - 10174

10.1C00 - 10212
10.1C01 - 10213
10.1C02 - 10213
10.1C03 - 10213
10.1C04 - 10215

10.2A00 - 12003
10.2A01 - 12008
10.2A02 - 12008
10.2A03 - 12009

10.2B00 - 12371
10.2B01 - 12372
10.2B02 - 12372
10.2B03 - 12372
10.2B04 - 12382
10.2B05 - 12383
10.2B06 - 12384
10.2B07 - 12385
10.2B08 - 12403

Progress 9.1D to 9.1E Shared Memory Versions:

9.1D00 - 9118
9.1D01 - 9122
9.1D02 - 9124
9.1D03 - 9124
9.1D04 - 9125
9.1D05 - 9126
9.1D06 - 9127
9.1D07 - 9128
9.1D08 - 9129

9.1E00 - 9135
9.1E01 - 9136
9.1E02 - 9171
9.1E03 - 9200
9.1E04 - 9200

Older Shared Memory Versions:

9.0x - 9000 +
8.0x - 8001 +
7.4x - 7400 +
7.3B - 7331 +
7.3A - 7301 +
7.2x - 70xx
7.1x - 70xx
7.0x - 70xx
6.3x - 63xx
6.2x - 6xx
5.2x - 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct way as in MS SQL Server. But, as a workaround, you can define a procedure/user defined function (UDF) (if you are using 11.7) to get version. As you should write procedure/UDF in java, you can write some piece of code to get the version. For example, you can create a .p to get the version and call that .p from java code in procedure/UDF. In the .p file, you can use PROVERSION statement to get version. Later, you can call that procedure/UDF from SQL.